# Why emulator or Genymotion is unable to run my app properly?

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

I am using Genymotion for personal use to test my apps.
However, the emulator opens up, displays everything fine.
As soon as I run my app, it hangs or crashes.Same is happening when I use default android emulator.
Also its taking quite too long to open my default emulator.
I checked HAX on console and it is running fine.
My system RAM is 8Gb.
It appears to me some memory like issue but cannot figure it out exactly.

Comment: "As soon as I run my app, it hangs or crashes", can you post logcat error ?

Comment: emulator crashes so app install fails. so is there any way to allocate some memory to emulator?

Comment: Launch the emulator using terminal, then you will get dump of the error on your terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with ...

The solution that worked for me with x86 emulator was to update HAXM with the last version and to restart my computer.

http://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

may be this also works for you

The root cause was a missing video driver (the vanilla Microsoft one wasn't enough). I was working with a cobbled-together frankenbox and found it useful to follow the instructions on finding the right driver here:

http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/HowtoidentifythemodelofanATIgraphicscard.aspx#DID

I hope it helps